# Eclipse Android XML content assist not working

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout, editor

My content assist was working for `Eclipse XML (android)` until I did an update of the android sdk, now the "design" of my xml files isn't a graphical view and when I use `CTRL+space`, I always get these four non-usable suggestions:

```
"default namespace - Default namespace attribute", 
"noschemaLoc - no namespace schema location",
"schemaLoc- XML schema location attribute",  
"xsinsp - XML schema namespace"
```

I also installed dreamweaver which may have interfeared with the XML extension.

A suggested solution is to `right click` on the `.xml` file and select *choose another program* called "*Android Layout Editor*". But I can't find it anywhere, I think it might not be on my computer.

I have also tried changing workspace without any success.

Any suggestions how to fix this ?

Answer (score 16):

Right click on xml file and select openwith option and you can find  Android Layout Editor.

Comment: Android Layout Editor doesn't show up, I even tried searching in all the locations I thought it would be in with no luck...

Comment: 1. adobe dreamweaver cs5
2. microsoft info path 2010
3. microsoft word
4. notepad
5. wordpad
6. xml editor (dreamweaver)

Comment: user1084928 it sounds like you are right clicking from explorer not eclipse. I had same problem, right clicking the xml inside eclipse should give you the option.

Comment: Yep Tony, your exactly right. I just solved the problem 10 seconds before I wanted to update this! 

Thanks everybody!

Comment: @user493244 tysm it helps

Answer (score 2):

If your content assist is working for java but not for xml, go to `window-> preferences->xml->content assist`  and:

- set the delay to 20 ms instaed of 500
- set the suggestion strategy to LAX
- add the entire alphabet to `prompt when these characters are inserted: <=:azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn`

These are the things that worked for me, and programming with content assist is so much easier
;)

Answer (score 1):

Update to ADT 16 which came out yesterday; the bug should be fixed there. ("The bug" being the bug that in ADT 14 and ADT 15, many newly added XML files would end up being assigned to the default XML editor instead of the customized Android XML editors.)

Answer (score 1):

Re-install the SDK android-platform that you are working with. The resource files may be corrupted **[e.g. android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-10\data\res\values\attrs.xml]**.

Answer (score 1):

It's android sdk problem just change android currently version to another one

like if you are currently using android 2.3.2 than change it to  android 2.3.3 i have tested it's currently  working fine!!!

You can change it through PROJECT->PROPERTY->ANDROID now on that change version

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set the default editor in Eclipse Preferences, used Android Common XML Editor.
You find it in Eclipse Preferences, General, Editors, File Associations. Click on .xml, choose "Add" "Android Common XML Editor". Select it and press the Default button.

Answer (score 0):

very helpful i am jut following  Step
click on xml file-right click on file -then choose the  Android Layout Editor.