# Android: Eclipse autocomplete does not work in xml files

Tags: android, eclipse

I am seeing a strange problem with my Eclipse IDE for Android development.

Autocompletion does not work when I hit Ctrl + Space in the main.xml file for my layouts. In the bottom left, I get a message saying for example "LinearLayout not found".

I also have the correct namespace specified in my file.

It does work though for other xml files, such as my strings.xml which I find strange.

This is an annoyance as I'd like to easily see all the options available for a View or Layout.

Anyone got any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Sure that you added the XML-Namepsace for android: `<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" .../>`

Comment: Yes, I have the namespace added. I will edit my post to clarify

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check that the file is being opened in the Android XML Layout editor (not just the "plain" XML editor). Right-click the file, choose **Open With**, and select **Android Layout Editor**.

Comment: Or **Android Common XML Editor** if you don't have Layout http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/4F/14/47c21898788f4f14.png

Answer (score 3):

It seems like an eclipse XML editor issue.
If you declare the xmlns in other than "xmlns:android" you loose the autocompletion.

for example if you say:

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:.... //AUTOCOMPLETES
```

if you say

```
 xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android1:... //DOES NOT AUTOCOMPLETE
```

Answer (score 1):

Open eclipse and go to the following:

```
Window > preferences > XML > editor > content assist > advanced
```

Select all checkboxes and click ok. After that, restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as suggested [powder366](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413198/eclipse-android-xml-content-assist-not-working)

> Or you can set the default editor in Eclipse Preferences, used Android Common XML Editor. You find it in Eclipse Preferences, General, Editors, File Associations. Click on .xml, choose "Add" "Android Common XML Editor". Select it and press the Default button.

Answer (score 0):

OPEN YOUR FILE WITH GENERIC TEXT EDITOR

Right-click on XML File, select Open with GENERIC TEXT EDITOR

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31240264)

Answer (score 0):

Check that the file is being opened in the **Generic text editor**.If not then, Right-click the file, choose Open With, and select **Generic text Editor.**