# why i am not getting android:background option in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-background

I am trying to setup a splash screen. When I am adding a background in `LinearLayout`, the xml is not showing me the `android:background` option.
I have already added the (600 X 400).png image into @drawable/hdpi folder.
Please help me out.

Comment: May be intellisense is broken in your Eclipse, if you add it manually does it work?

Comment: what is the name of your png file?

Comment: I use Eclipse and sometimes it doesn't tell me which attributes I can use, mostly when I have custom schemas as well declared in my xml along with the default xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: @M-WaJeEh  name of the image is "splash_backgroung"

Comment: have you tried to Clean your project ?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Eclipse autocomplete does not work in xml files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114335/android-eclipse-autocomplete-does-not-work-in-xml-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always happens for me. Make sure you already added the image in your drawable folder and then Clean your project. It's all Eclipse's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Xml editors get messy sometimes, I use `ctrl+shift+f` and it works again, but it doesnt happen that often in most recent ADT.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen sometime to me too, for no particular reason whatsoever.
However, if you just write it down, without suggestion from eclipse, it will still be shown :)

Comment: It would be nice to figure out why it happens and how to get it working again, I have seen that in some xml it doesn't work and in another in same project it works.

Comment: I honestly never gave it too much thought. It can be just an annoying little bug in Eclipse. Same thing as you sometimes have to build your project in order for java to recorgnise your new layout, when you're trying to setContentView.

Comment: Also, similar bug to this one is with the Xcode, when you dont get a sugestion for some ViewController.h, when you are trying to connect actual layout to the class....this doesn't have to do much with this question, Im just reffering that it might be some minor thing

Comment: Thank You guys , it was happening cz of Eclipse only , just cleaned my project and i was good to go .. bt surely it's a headache..