# No layout_width attribute shown in option list when using Drawerlayout in ADT

Tags: android

I am new to Android, I studied the navigation drawer example from Google
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

I imported and run this example well in eclipse(ADT), but there is one question about the layout file which is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

.........

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Usually, when I press CTRL+SPACE, Eclipse will show a content assist list, but when I want to do it for Framelayout's layout_width attribute, I can not find it in that assist list. Could any one tell me how to make it shown in assist list?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using support package Widgets this is a common scenario (a weird one too).

Here you using, `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` and hence the issue. Happened with me a lot of time.

You can also try couple of options mentioned [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114335/android-eclipse-autocomplete-does-not-work-in-xml-files)

Comment: Nice to hear that Kuan. :)