# content assist is not available at current location error if I use ctrl+space for the views declared inside <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, space, ctrl

I am using eclipse Juno in ubuntu 12.04 environment for android app development. I am facing one very strange problem with eclipse. Whenever I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> I get error saying

> content assist is not available at current location

This is only happening when I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>for the views declared inside `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>` tag.

I googled a lot, but dint find working solution. Some people responded that

> Here you using, android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout and hence the
>   issue

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537733/no-layout-width-attribute-shown-in-option-list-when-using-drawerlayout-in-adt)

Please check my xml file below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->



        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
            android:columnWidth="50dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:rowHeight="50dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
        </GridView>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#f4f4f4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_list1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_gray_back"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now If I remove

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

everything works perfectly. all the attributes of the `GridView` are showing in suggestion by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>. So I figured out the problem is occurring due to  `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`.

How can I resolve this issue, because I must have to use above tab in xml?